# How to build submodule in android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, baresip

I have build HelloWorld example successfully in NDK.

I want to build the libraries re-0.4.2, rim and baresip.

Project structure shown in image

[image]

How to build above lib?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212869/calling-inner-android-mk-file-to-build-prebuilt-libraries-not-working/10428651#10428651

Comment: thanks Samveen, I know that but I want to invoke Makefile of baresip, re-0.4.2 and rem-0.4.2 in Android.mk. Actually I am able to build library using linux command prompt by calling make command. could you please suggest me how to invoke makefile from Android.mk?

Comment: I don't recommend mixing and matching different build systems. That said, I haven't employed calling make directly in `Android.mk`.

Comment: @Samveen: Launching `make` from `Android.mk` is as simple as it could be: `Android.mk` is nothing but an _included_ part of a huge `Makefile` (namely, `$(NDK_ROOT)/build/core/build-local.mk`).

Comment: @Mukesh: if the question is still relevant, and if you don't care about running `./configure` for each submodule, but have the makefiles tuned for cross-compilation to **bionic** and relevant ABI (probably, **armeabi**), then all you have to do is add the three targets to the bottom of your `Android.mk`, with recipes like `$(MAKE) -C rem-0.4.2` (see http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion for details)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a project that shows how to cross-compile Baresip
for Android. You can find it here on Github:

https://github.com/alfredh/baresip-android

Comment: @alfredh i have read that baresip is a user agen means that it will be installed on android like any other application?

Comment: I am getting problem during compilation. check it http://askubuntu.com/questions/844977/re-h-no-such-file-or-directory.