# Android NDK stand alone compilation getting error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am using NDK stand alone compilation.

But,getting error like this

home/umn/android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lssl 
/home/umn/android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lcrypto 
            collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
        make[3]: *** [addrinfo] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/umn/AndroidStudioProjects/webRTC_Sofia_Android/app/src/main/jni/sofia-sip/libsofia-sip-ua/su' make[2]: *** [install] Error 2 
    make[2]: Leaving directory` 
/home/umn/AndroidStudioProjects/webRTC_Sofia_Android/app/src/main/jni/sofia-sip/libsofia-sip-ua/su' 
    make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1 
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/umn/AndroidStudioProjects/webRTC_Sofia_Android/app/src/main/jni/sofia-sip/libsofia-sip-ua' make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

And my build code posted below:

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/home/umn/android/android-ndk-r10e
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/
export LOCAL_LDLIBS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16"
LDFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lssl"
export CC="$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.9 --sysroot=$SYSROOT"
./configure \
--host=arm-linux-androideabi \
--prefix=$(pwd) \
--exec-prefix=$(pwd) \
--disable-shared
make clean
make
make install
```

Comment: The linker can't find libssl or libcrypto. The accepted answer here may be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531390/use-libcryto-so-and-libssl-so-in-an-android-project

Comment: I am using stand alone compiler. not using any .mk file.