# opendl failed in alljoynlib in android

Tags: android, dlopen, alljoyn

I have an `alljoyn` library in my project to pair android devices for a voting app. In old devices the app runs properly but in new devices it stops when it is starting to run.

This is the error, I got:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libcrypto.so" not found
                      at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
                      at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
                      at com.example.nima.voting.alljoyn.peergroupmanager.PeerGroupManager.<clinit>(PeerGroupManager.java:60)
```

Comment: How are you importing libcrypto.so into PeerGroupManager.java?  Include the import statement in the body of your question.

Comment: static {
        System.loadLibrary("alljoyn_java");
    }

Comment: which alljoyn version are you using? on which Android version the app does not work?

Comment: If the below answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as the selected answer.  If not, consider specifying why it wasn't helpful, so we can continue helping you solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: I'm not an Android developer.

That said, I found [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531390/use-libcryto-so-and-libssl-so-in-an-android-project), which mentions similar behavior to what you described:

> The master Android process is `zygote`. Its like `init` in Linux. Zygote
>   loads OpenSSL when its start, and it loads version 0.9.8. If you link
>   against OpenSSL 1.0.1, then you will get mysterious runtime crashes.
>   The crashes are due to the Android loader using the 0.9.8 version of
>   the library (already mapped from Zygote), and not your version of
>   OpenSSL.
>
> You *can* use a shared object, but your shared object must be a wrapper around the static version of `libssl` and `libcrypto`.

You mentioned that the app loads properly in old devices but crashes in new devices.  If the new devices are linking against OpenSSL v1.0.1 and the old ones against v0.9.8, then this might be the root cause of your problem.

The solution seems to be either to compile against static libraries for `libcrypto` (and for `libssl` too, apparently), or to rename these dependencies after the build, then copy them into your `precompiled` directory (if I interpreted the answer in the link correctly):

> The reason is that the system comes with its own (probably different)
>   version of these shared libraries, and the loader will use
>   `/system/lib/libssl.so` and `/system/lib/libcrypto.so` instead of your
>   private copies.

Comment: Actually I rerun an old project which is running perfectly in android lollipop and older version, but it crashes with mentioned error in later android version.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the solution seems to be either to compile against static libraries for `libcrypto` and `libssl`, or to rename these dependencies after the build, then copy them into your `precompiled` directory.  See the link at the start of my answer for more complete context.